# Ubuntu user logon script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo

I have a bash script in /etc/profile.d/run1.sh that I want all users to run upon logon:

```
#!/bin/bash
# run1.sh
sudo /usr/local/bin/run2.bash
```

The file is readable and executable by everyone (chmod 755)

A graphical dialog box is displayed on login with the following text:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
unknown': I need something more specific.

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
                [OK]
```

A more precise screenshot can be seen at https://share.icloud.com/photos/0rFXpZNltiSogcz1hzlmWTIUg

The script in /etc/profile.d is used to launch another script with sudo.  That script is identified in  a special file in `/etc/sudoers.d/run_script`:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/run2.bash
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: Please share both the error message and the logon script here in text form. Don't use images for text-only content

Comment: Images don't count as content "included in the question itself" for purposes of [mcve] rules. They can't be copied-and-pasted to test; they can't be searched; they aren't friendly to assistive technologies like screen readers; they can't be analyzed for nonprinting characters.

Comment: Check your `journalctl` logs for more detail.

Comment: It would also help to try to comply with [mcve] rules more generally -- that is, to provide the shortest possible code that someone else can use to see the same error themselves. We don't necessarily want your actual script, but we can't test a fix for a bug if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Updated with some additional info.